# Counting Shapes/Objects Created Continuously within Processing

Tags: object, processing, shapes

My code takes an image and creates a pointillist image through creating ellipses with a pixel's color.

After a while, the image is fully 'painted' and I want to automatically switch to another image in my sketch folder.

I would like to be able to count the number of ellipses generated. Once 'z' ellipses are generated I want to tell my code to erase all ellipses and start over with a new image.

CODE:

```java
PImage img;
int smallPoint, largePoint;

void setup() {
  size(1920, 1080);
  img = loadImage("rio.jpg");
  smallPoint = 12;
  largePoint = 12;
  imageMode(CENTER);
  noStroke();
  background(255);
}

void draw() { 



 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    drawADot();
  }
}

void drawADot()
{

  int imageWidth = img.width;
  int imageHeight = img.height;
  int ptSize = int(random(100)) + 4;

  float pointillize = map(mouseX, 0, width, smallPoint, largePoint); //not used right now but for controlling ellipse size
  int x = int(random(0, imageWidth/8));
  int y = int(random(0, imageHeight/8));




    color pix = img.get(x*8, y*8);
    fill(pix, 255);
    ellipse(x*8, y*8, pointillize, pointillize);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the images in an array, count the dots added, and conditionally (based in number of dots) change the image being used to next one in the array, you can pass the image to the `drawADot()` function as a parameter. Something like:

```java
PImage img[] = new PImage[2];
int smallPoint, largePoint;
final int DOTSPERDRAW = 500;
int numberOfDots = 0;
final int MAXDOTS = DOTSPERDRAW * 100; 
PImage workingImage ;
int index;

void setup() {
  size(810, 455);
  img[0] = loadImage("http://assets2.exame.abril.com.br/assets/images/2014/8/506584/size_810_16_9_rio.jpg");
  img[1] = loadImage("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Pilcomayo_rio.jpg");
  img[1].resize(810, 0);
  smallPoint = 12;
  largePoint = 12;
  imageMode(CENTER);
  noStroke();
  background(255);
  workingImage = img[0];
}

void draw() { 

  if (numberOfDots > MAXDOTS) {
    index = (index + 1) % img.length;
    workingImage = img[index];
    numberOfDots = 0;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < DOTSPERDRAW; i++)
  {
    drawADot(workingImage);
  }

  numberOfDots += DOTSPERDRAW;
}

void drawADot(PImage theImage)
{

  int imageWidth = theImage.width;
  int imageHeight = theImage.height;
  int ptSize = int(random(100)) + 4;

  float pointillize = map(mouseX, 0, width, smallPoint, largePoint); //not used right now but for controlling ellipse size
  int x = int(random(0, imageWidth/8));
  int y = int(random(0, imageHeight/8));




  color pix = theImage.get(x*8, y*8);
  fill(pix, 255);
  ellipse(x*8, y*8, pointillize, pointillize);
}
```

Comment: Worked exactly as I wanted. Thank you for your help!